# How do I store vars for dom elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I have is multiple dynamic divs that animate when clicked, Basically I want to save the state of the div when its clicked, so if I click on it again, it will remember what state its in.  Right now I have it working, but if I click on the firs div, it changes the global state of all the divs. so if I then click on div 2, it does nothing, because its already in that state. I have to click it twice for it to work.

See my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zdh2d/)

```
  var next_move = "expand";
  $(".slide").click(function()
    {
        var css = {};
        if (next_move == "expand"){
            css = {
            right: '100px'
            };
            next_move = "shrink";
        } else {
            css = {
            right: '0px'
            };     
            next_move = "expand";
        }
        $(this).animate(css, 200);
    });
```

I assume I have to create an object to hold the properties some how.

Comment: your fiddle is working fine

Comment: @BharathRallapalli click on the fist div, then the second. You have to click the second twice, because  it thinks its already expanded.

Comment: In your fiddle (at this moment), you have repeating ids (same id on more than one element). Although this is not related to the problem, but you should keep in mind that the id must be unique for the entire page. It is not clear how jQuery selectors will behave otherwise

Comment: Do not use same ids for more than one element!...

Comment: @IvayloSlavov thanks for the tip, I will not use repeating ids from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `data()` method to store the state relative to the element :

```
$(".slide").click(function () {
    var expand = $(this).data('expand');
    $(this).animate({right: (expand?0:100)}, 200).data('expand', !expand);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdh2d/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another class which will say if the div is expanded or not

```
$( ".slide" ).click( function() {
    var css = {};
    if( $( this ).hasClass( "expanded" ) ) {
       css = {
                        right: '0px'
        };  

        $( this ).removeClass( "expanded" );
    } else {
        css = {
                        right: '100px'
        };

        $( this ).addClass( "expanded" );
    }

    $( this ).animate( css, 200 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the `$(this)` will fix it. You can have a `data-attribute` to have the current state.

```
var next_move = "expand";
        $(".slide").click(function()
    {
        var css = {};
        if ($(this).css('right') == "0px"){
            css = {
                            right: '100px'
            };
        } else {
            css = {
                            right: '0px'
            };     
        }
        $(this).animate(css, 200);
    });
```